# NextJS importing entire sass files/modules in a page or component

Tags: import, sass, next.js

I'm trying import css just like I do normally in react.

```js
import "@styles/my_lovely_component.sass"
```

It obviously shows the error that *I cannot import global styles in components.* If I change the name from `my_lovely_component.sass` to `my_lovely_component.module.sass`, the error is suppressed but the styles aren't really applied/included on my page or components.

I found out people use component styles like this

```js
import styles from "@styles/my_lovely_component.module.sass"

const JustAComponent = () => <img className={styles.doggo_img} />
```

This gets annoying very quickly. I literally have been working by importing all styles globally in `__app.ts`, because I couldn't find a working solution to import styles like the good old(well not really old) way.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

*(I did consider the other styling methods like styled-jsx/components, emotion and stuff. But they're even more annoying.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add global styles for your next project

At first you need loader in next-config.js
then read about _document.js where you can add global styles to the head.

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint. But it looks whatever I put there applies globally ? Thats not what I'm looking for.
I have style files (sass/css) for each page and I want to import them for the respective pages, not really globally. Can I do that? :/